# How to do default layout from Devexpress Gridview

Tags: xml, gridview, devexpress

I have a question about C# Devexpress,I wanto to do when i click a button it will load default layout gridview from xml file.I hope I colud explain what i want to do ,so Thank you for helps!

Answer (score 0):

At first, take a look at the [Saving and Restoring Layouts](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument772) help-article and the [BaseView.RestoreLayoutFromXml](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseBaseView_RestoreLayoutFromXmltopic(mB9lhA)) method:

```
using DevExpress.XtraGrid;
// ...
string fileName = "c:\\DefaultLayout.xml";
void buttonRestoreLayout_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
   gridView1.RestoreLayoutFromXml(fileName);
}
```

Have you running into a problem with this?